# Phonegap onclick not working

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am new on phonegap and I am having a big problem with a button. When I execute on a browser it works perfect and insert in my DB correctly, but whe I am using phonegap developer it doesn't work, nothing happens...Could someone help me please?

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form_cadastrar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="formCliente" >
        <div id="control">  
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="cad-titulo">
                    <span>Posso te conhecer?</span>
                </div>
            </div>             
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Nome
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input  type="text" autofocus name="nome" id="nome" class="campos" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Sobrenome
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" class="campos" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    CPF
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="888.888.888-88" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="campos" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Email
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="campos" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Crie&nbsp;uma&nbsp;senha
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha1" class="campos">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    Repita&nbsp;a&nbsp;senha
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="senha2" id="senha2" class="campos">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="control-group">
                <input onclick="enviar()" type="button"><span>ENVIAR</span></button>
                </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                <button onClick="history.go(-1)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span>VOLTAR</span></button>
                </div>   
            </div>

         </div>   

        </form>  

    </body>

</html>    

      <script>
function enviar(){ 
var formula = $('#formCliente').serialize();

$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    data: formula,
    url:'http://localhost/teste/www/cadastrar.php',
    success: function(data){

    if(data == '' || data == 0){
        alert('Occoreu um erro no Banco de Dados');
        window.location = "";
    }

    if(data == 1){
        alert('registro salvo com sucesso'); 
         window.location.href = "login.html";   
        }


    }


});

}

</script>
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'pass';
$database = 'mydb';

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username,    
$password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    //echo 'Conexao efetuada com sucesso!';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO usuario (nome, sobrenome, cpf, email, senha)' ;
 $sql .= 'VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :cpf, :email, :senha)';

try {

$recebeConexao = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$recebeConexao->bindParam(':nome', $_POST['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':sobrenome', $_POST['sobrenome'],  
PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':cpf', $_POST['cpf'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':senha', $_POST['senha'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$recebeConexao->execute();

if($recebeConexao == true){
$cadastro = 1;
}else{
$cadastro = 0;
}


} catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "Erro inserção";
}
echo (json_encode($cadastro));

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have potentially a couple of problems here... your Ajax request is going to localhost which on the device will be the device itself.  You will need to replace that with the IP address or hostname of the machine your PHP is running on and ensure that the phone can see that machine (usually by having them both on the same wireless network).

Additionally if you are using Cordova 5 for Android and/or iOS you may also need to add a proper Content Security Policy meta tag to permit Ajax requests to your server.  For example, add something like this into the head of your index.html for your Cordova app:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://YOUR_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS">
```

For running on iOS 9 you will also want to configure a proper exception to the App Transport Security (ATS) that iOS 9 introduces if your server is not secured with SSL.  To do this you modify the plist for your project with a list of servers you want to allow non SSL connections to.  So you would add something like this to the iOS project's .plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
      <key>yourservergoeshere.com</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

A proper discussion of both of these issues is [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).

Comment: It works and I don't know how to thank you, I am trying to fix this since last week(tryed almost everything) and I almost lost my semester on university because of this. Thank you very much!